# Отправка на сервер JSON с новой строкой

Tags: javascript, java

Есть JSON

```
{dev: "что такое а потом \n
новая строка"}
```

Как отправить его на сервер, чтобы пришел с символом новой строки а не `\n`? Сейчас приходит не символ новой строки, а слэш и `n`, которая тоже печатается.

Comment: Наверное, это всё-таки забота средства отображения/печати - правильно интерпретировать управляющие символы.

Comment: я бы отправлял так, а при выводе заменял \n на </br>

Comment: а куда он приходит ? может просто сделать .toString() к этой строке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, то что Вы хотите сделать - невозможно и это в порядке вещей.

И  это(`\n`) нормально!

При кодировании JSON символы новой строки специально экранируются, поскольку символы перехода строки в строке в JSON недопустимы и то, что вы хотите передать будет являться невалидным JSON'ом и при разборе вызовет ошибку.

**Этого требует спецификация!**

И наоборот: если Вы получите на сервере JSON с `\n` то после разбора JSON Вы обратно получите нормальную строку с нормальным символом перехода строки и никаких других специальных действий предпринимать не нужно. (Во всяком случае в тех библиотеках, которыми я пользуюсь - это так)

Другими словами то, что Вы туда клали, то Вы и получите и на промежуточный результат Вам смотреть не стоит.

Кстати строковый ключ без кавычек валидатор у меня тоже не пропускает.

Валидный вариант будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
{
    "dev": "что такое а потом \nновая строка"
}
```

Доверьте библиотекам кодировать и декодировать JSON.